# Implementing a message/subscription mechanism in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, message

I'm prototyping a WPF application with the MVVM pattern. Following an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361687/interaction-of-view-models-in-mvvm) I have set up a `ModelProviderService` which exposes models as properties. The consumers of the service are the viewmodels, i.e. they pull their models from the service instead of instantiating them theirselves.

```
class ModelProviderService {

  private LoginModel loginModel;
  public LoginModel LoginModel {
    get { return loginModel; }
    set { loginModel = value; }
  }

  private ProjectsModel projectsModel;
  public ProjectsModel ProjectsModel {
    get { return projectsModel; }
    set { projectsModel = value; }
  }

  public ModelProviderService() {
    loginModel = new LoginModel();
    projectsModel = new ProjectsModel();
  }    
}
```

Now, here is what shall happen:

- A viewmodel changes a property of e.g. the `LoginModel` property.
- The viewmodel pushes the model property back to the service by setting its property: `modelService.LoginModel.MyProperty = localLoginModel.MyProperty;`
- The service shall publish a message: "Hey, my model of type `LoginModel` just changed."
- Any other viewmodel that has subscribed to this message will pull this changed model from the service.

How can I implement:

1. the "broadcast message"?
2. the subscription to the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `MessageBus` or `EventAggregator` to publish messages to subscribers by using weak references. Take a look at [my implementation](https://github.com/khellang/Hellang.MessageBus) (or [the NuGet packgage](http://nuget.org/packages/Hellang.MessageBus)).

It can also marshal the message handling to the UI thread for you (if you need to update UI components) by applying the `HandleOnUIThreadAttribute` on the `Handle` method.

Usage in your case would be something like:

```
// The message
public class LoginModelChanged
{
    public LoginModelChanged(LoginModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public LoginModel Model { get; private set; }
}

// Service that publishes messages
public class ModelProviderService
{
    private IMessageBus _messageBus;
    private LoginModel _loginModel;

    public ModelProviderService(IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        _messageBus = messageBus;
    }

    public LoginModel LoginModel
    {
        get { return _loginModel; }
        set
        {
            _loginModel = value;
            _messageBus.Publish(new LoginModelChanged(value));
        }
    }
}

// Subscribing ViewModel
public class SomeViewModel : IHandle<LoginModelChanged>
{
    public SomeViewModel(IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        messageBus.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(LoginModelChanged message)
    {
        // Do something with message.Model
    }
}
```

If you want to know more about the inner workings and how to implement this; Check out the source code in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/khellang/Hellang.MessageBus). Feel free to use the code as you like :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to distribute messages inside a WPF application, you may go with [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) of [prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework.

EventAggregator allows viewmodels to weakly subsribe to events, requiring no knowledge about the sender. This allows you to easily distribute messages accross components or modules.