# BackgroundWorker in ViewModel MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker, viewmodel

From what I understand, the `ViewModel` should only contain validation methods, properties, and Commands. There shouldn't be any programming functionality in the `ViewModel`.

In my program, I want to start threads when a property changes. For example, every time the user types something in a textbox, a new thread is started. Can I have methods like `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`, `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`, and `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` defined in my `ViewModel`?

Comment: Although not entirely clear what your requirements are, but to me it sounds a perfect case to use [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). For example with your textbox text change, check this 2 part blogs on msdn [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/archive/2013/06/21/an-rx-enabled-wpf-control-part-1-2.aspx) and [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/archive/2013/06/21/an-rx-enabled-wpf-control-part-2-2.aspx). Although you don't need autocomplete, but they might illustrate the point of using Rx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338536/mvvm-viewmodel-and-business-logic-connection This has an excellent answer by a user called Jon. I'd recommend reading it.

Comment: "_Every time the user types something in a textbox, a new thread is started_" Well, there goes your CPU. Did you mean that a new thread is started which monitors any changes and fires those events? Or events are added to a queue that fires them from a separate thread?

Comment: *There shouldn't be any programming functionality in the ViewModel.* Nope. And that's why you have a problem.  Also, get with the times.  Use Tasks rather than the old hackneyed BackgroundWorker stuff.

Comment: What Daniel Lane referring is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338888/1977871)

Comment: @Will Then where you put the code? What is the alternative?

Comment: @Phil1970 Your question doesn't make sense.  But your code, you put it *where it makes sense*.  Nothing says that place isn't in a view model.

Comment: @Will Well as in the original question, I try to figure out what is the best way to have something that run in background and report progress... I have not used WPF much and even less MVVM. You suggest not to put code in ViewModel and to uses Tasks but it would be helpful if you would write a more detailed answer that show how you would do that.

Comment: Many have given some comments or links... but it would be useful to have a specific answer on either the best way to use a background worker or if you think that alternatives are more appropriates, then a "pattern" on how you would implement something that replace all the functionalities of a background worker (reporting progress, allowing cancellation, allows to return a final result, and allows to detect if some processing is in progress).

Comment: @Phil1970 oh, you misread me.  Or I was a bit unclear.  I quoted the line "There shouldn't be any programming functionality in the ViewModel" and said ***Nope.*** meaning that I disagree with that statement.  There are a few good patterns for doing what you ask, including using async/await in the view model to move from the UI context to a worker thread and back again without any difficulty.  That's my new fav, which often suggests a layer transition (vm => BLL, which exposes async methods).

Comment: I'll pin this and come back to it when I have time, I suppose I could answer with a couple different versions of the pattern...